# how do I pause a wpf animation using code behind?

Tags: wpf, animation

Given my animation `scene1`. How can I pause it using a button named “Skip” using `C# code` behind, and play another animation `scene2` after.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="scene1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="whitebox">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.7" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" Storyboard.TargetName="charName">
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="Teacher"/>
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7.8" Value="Teacher"/>
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="Teacher"/>
        </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment)" Storyboard.TargetName="charName">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="{x:Static HorizontalAlignment.Left}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7.8" Value="{x:Static HorizontalAlignment.Left}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="{x:Static HorizontalAlignment.Left}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        (too long… etc.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Jeric Paul Calderon's answer, there's also pause function : `storyBoard.Pause()` 
The main thing is that `Pause()` pauses the annimation at the current playback position, and `Stop()` does stop and returns to the starting point.

Comment: thank you.. I want to pause it on it's current position.. So pause is the thing i need...same as what I replied to Jeric scene1 automatically starts when the form loads... I want to stop it manually using code behind through the skip button and at the same time play scene2... Is that possible?

Comment: of course yes ! just call the scene 2 like this : Storyboard scene2 = this.Resources["scene2"] as Storyboard; and do play it. you can joggle with'm as you like.

Comment: It really helped a lot.. but after pausing an error message appeared "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." the error points out my codes for the pause button which is: Storyboard scene1 = this.Resources["scene_1"] as Storyboard; scene1.Pause();

Answer (score 2):

In code behind, use this.Resources["scene1"] to get the Storyboard object.

```
Storyboard storyBoard = this.Resources["scene1"] as Storyboard;
storyBoard.Begin();
```

Use the Storyboard "Completed" event to start another animation when Storyboard has completed

```
storyBoard.Completed += eventHandler
```

Call

```
storyBoard.Stop()
```

to stop the animation.

Comment: well, the thing is scene1 automatically starts when the form loads... I want to stop it manually using code behind through the skip button and at the same time play scene2... Is that possible?